# How to know undisclosed-recipients in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-client

I have received the mail with undisclosed-recipients, How can i see the same?

Comment: I think the whole point of undisclosed recipients is that you *don't get to know* who received the message.

Comment: If you can't see them how do you know they're there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Undisclosed means just that. You can't see them because they're not disclosed. The email was sent to [BCC (blind carbon copy)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy) addresses.

Comment: Yaa, you are right but there should be a way(ethical or non- ethical).

Comment: @Sandy: It's done at the sending side, so it's impossible. It's the same as if I sent the same email to two different addresses separately.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Dennis for quick reply. I got its not possible.Thanx again.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. This would indicate the sender used BCC: instead of CC: thereby masking the list of recipients with no addresses shared among recipients. Apologies for a lack of solution...